# Visual Studio 2013 Button Not Working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been trying to create my first software with Visual Studio 2013. I wanted to create an LLS (Last login stealer). The LLS is for experimental and educational purposes ONLY. When someone puts information into TextBox1 only, and tries to press Button1, none of the code that is supposed to happen happens. Here is some of the code for Button1.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Username is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")

        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Password is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")

            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("IP address is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")
            Else
                Dim IOP As String
                IOP = "Instant OP"
                Timer1.Start()
                ProgressBar1.Value = 0
                Button1.Enabled = False
                Button2.Enabled = False
                Button3.Enabled = False
                Button4.Enabled = False
                TextBox1.Enabled = False
                TextBox2.Enabled = False
                TextBox3.Enabled = False
                ComboBox1.Enabled = False
                Dim bypass As String
                bypass = "Accessing Server Console IP "
                Dim ws As String
                ws = ComboBox1.Text
                MsgBox(bypass + TextBox3.Text + " on " + ws, MsgBoxStyle.Information, IOP)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms program? And indenting your code will help a lot.

Comment: Visual Studio is a development environment. It supports many completely different programming languages. When you ask questions it helps a lot if you specify, which programming language you used.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code formatting, which makes the issue obvious.  The only way that code in the `Else` block is going to be executed is if the first two `TextBox` controls are empty and the third is not, which is completely wrong.  Your code should be like this:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Username is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")
ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Password is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")
ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("IP address is missing.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Instant OP")
Else
    '...
End If
```

That way, your code will only be executed if all three `TextBox` controls are NOT empty.